# class WP_Widget - Different dashboard preview for custom widget

Tags: wordpress, widget, dashboard

I was looking help earlier on Wordpress Stack Exchange but no response i got.

I try to create custom widget to display specified category latest-posts on home page. Unfortunately outcome of my php code print a lot of html elements so on dashboard widgets page the preview is unneccessary huge. For example it display a featured images of listed posts.

Is there any solution to have different preview of my widget on dashboard in contrast to what my widget show on home page?

I tried in my php use is_admin() function but it does not work.

**EDIT:**
I found a solution. Here is the link to my answer under another topic.
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/419835/84343.
It's useful on old type of widgets.

Comment: You can try `is_front_page()` and `is_home()` maybe it will stop preview on widgets backend.

Comment: What a great idea! Why didn't I figure it out myself? :))) Thank You. Now i have what i need!

Answer (score -1):

Hi You can create new widget like this /

```
<?php

function wpb_widgets_init() {

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' => __( 'Main Sidebar', 'wpb' ),
    'id' => 'sidebar-1',
    'description' => __( 'The main sidebar appears on the right on each page except the front page template', 'wpb' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );

register_sidebar( array(
    'name' =>__( 'Front page sidebar', 'wpb'),
    'id' => 'sidebar-2',
    'description' => __( 'Appears on the static front page template', 'wpb' ),
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget' => '</aside>',
    'before_title' => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', 'wpb_widgets_init' );
```

and than you can use below code where you need to see this widget content

```
<?php if ( is_active_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ) ) : ?>
<div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'sidebar-1' ); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You did not understand well what i wrote. Dashboard is Wordpress admin panel. On Appearance > Widgets page you have preview of each used widget. When you click on it preview disappear and the widget edit settings form appears in his place. I need different preview there because in standard the preview show what is on your front-end page and in my case it's a lot of HTML elements with posts featured-images among them.